# lim inf, lim sup in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I am struggling with this question from an old measure theory question set, mainly because I'm confused by the notation.

Determine $\liminf A_n$ and $\limsup A_n$ for the sequence $(A_n)_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ of sets given by:
$$
A_n = 
\begin{cases} (-\frac{1}{n}-2,1)  & n \text{ odd}\\
(0,3+\frac{1}{n})  & n \text{ even}.
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly the odd sequence is converging to $(-2,1)$ and the even series is converging to $(0,3)$, but I don't know what $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ mean on ordered pairs like this.

*Edit:* Clearly I was over-thinking this - I thought I was dealing with ordered pairs from $\mathbb{R}^2$, when clearly these are open intervals on $\mathbb{R}$. Thank you to the people who set me straight.

Comment: They are open intervals. For a family $ F=\{F_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ of sets we have (i) $x\in \lim \inf F$ iff $\{n\in \Bbb N: x\not \in F_n\}$ is finite, and (ii) $x\in \lim\sup F$ iff $\{n\in \Bbb N: x\in F_n\}$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<x<1$ the $x$ clearly belongs to all of these sets. Suppose $y$ belongs to $A_n$ for all $n >n_0$ for some integer $n_0$. Then $-2-\frac  1 n <y<1$ for $n >n_0$ which implies $-2 \leq y <1$. Similarly we get $0 <y \leq 3$. Combining these we get $0<y<1$. Hence  $\lim \inf A_n =(0,1)$.
  Can you now verify that a point $x$ belongs to infinitely many of the set $A_n$ iff $x \in [-2,1) \cup (0,3]$. This part is easy so I will let you handle this.

Comment: Ah! The sets were intervals of $\mathbb{R}$! Now it all makes sense. Thank you.